# ubuntu 10.04 softRAID 5 partition scheme

Tags: boot, ubuntu-10.04, grub, software-raid, raid-5

I'm trying to create a RAID 5 array which will contain the Ubuntu installation itself.

I tried this partition scheme:

```
2.0 TB for /
6.0 GB for swap
```

This was as per the instructions provided by [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID).

Ubuntu installed successfully until the GRUB step at which it failed with an error that embedding is not supported without a /boot partition (Sorry, I lost the original error).

tl;dr **What kind of partition scheme is typically used for bootable softRAID 5?**

Answer (score 1):

You can't boot from software RAID5 directly. You should create a small RAID1 array to hold `/boot` and that should work fine.

I ran Ubuntu off a pair of SD cards in RAOD0 for a while when my netbook's internal SSD died, and all was fine with a small RAID1 array for `/boot` and the rest on a RAID0 array (it is not possible to boot from software RAID0 either).

**edit:** make sure you make `/boot` big enough to hold several kernels and initrds. As you seem to have plenty bit drives this shouldn't be a problem. My home server (which is possibly a pathological case having been Debian/Etch then upgraded to Etch-n-a-half then Lenny and having initially had -686 kernels then -amd64, and has never had such things properly cleared out, so has seven of everything in there) is using 96Mb of it's `/boot`, so 128Mb should be plenty (I usually go for 200Mb+ for /boot these days except on small SSDs - with the size of modern spinning-disk drives the space isn't missed elsewhere).

Comment: @David: That was true until recently, but Grub 2 has some support for RAID5, and booting from RAID5 is supported since Ubuntu 9.10 according to Ubuntu literature.

Comment: @Gilles: +1, I was unaware of that updated support in recent versions.

Comment: So I should create a `/boot` partition on all three drives and RAID1 them?

Comment: @Austin, yes that is how I normally do it. That way if any of the drives fall out of the array (i.e. one drive dies) you don't find `/boot` goes missing. Make sure that grub installs its bootloaded onto all three drives (IIRC grub2 detects the need for this so you might find it handled automatically with recent Ubuntu releases).

Comment: GRUB2 still fails to install (error about embedding) on this configuration.  I think I need to have a `biosgrub` partition not a `/boot` partition.

I also tried GRUB1 and LILO and neither work.  Any advice?

Comment: IIRC when I put Ubuntu on a pair of SD cards I needed to switch to another terminal and install grub manually to the two drives with something like `grub-install /dev/sdb` and `grub-install /dev/sdc` (in your case the drive's devices are more likely to be sda and sdb nor sdb and sdc) at the point where grub gets installed - but I was under the impression that the need for this is fixed in later releases (I was using 9.04 at the time).

Comment: Also, it is worth noting and quoting the exact error message that you get. I cringe (or sometimes rant) at work when I'm assigned to dealing with testing feedback that states "... and it reported an error"!